# Using :contains in jquery for xml parsing

Tags: jquery, xml, xml-parsing, contains

I am trying to take data from a large .xml file which contains quite unhelpful tags. These tags are all pretty much the same, and there is nothing I can do about the xml output. These xml documents will be updated quite regularly and I was hoping to automate a process for the website to take the relevant data easily. I was hoping to take the xml file and and use the :contains() action from jquery, but I cannot seem to make it work.

[XML file is here](http://pastebin.com/8GmYaM4k)

Here is my code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
<p id="manpower"></p>
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
$.ajax({
    type: "GET",
    url: "test.xml",
    dataType: "xml",
    success: function(xml) {
    $title = $(xml).find( "Key");

    $( "#manpower" ).append( $title.text() );
    }
});
});
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

So the code above works fine and it gives all the "Keys" however I would like to first find the  that :contains('time_cost') and then transverse through the children and hierarchy to the manpower data at the end of the xml file. The reason I need to do it like this is because in the full file there are multiple reference to manpower but the time_cost is unique. I would greatly appreciate it if someone could help with at least getting the closest function to work.

I have tried:

```
$title = $(xml).find( "Key:closest('time_cost')" );
```

But it doesn't work. I am quite new to jQuery so probably I am doing something quite trivial?

Here is a local jsFiddle version:
http://jsfiddle.net/yN3Sj/4/

Comment: Your question says "contains" but the code says "closest." Which is it?

Comment: what is the value, you want as the output

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why don't you do something like, it will give `Value` element which has the key `manpower`.

```
xmlDoc = $.parseXML( xml ),
$xml = $( xmlDoc ),
$time_cost = $(xml).find( "Key:contains('time_cost')" ),
$manpower = $('Key:contains("manpower")', $time_cost.parent()).parent();
```

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/yN3Sj/7/)

Comment: Hmm intersting, didn't think of it like that. The main issue is that there are multiple entries with 'manpower' and such so I ended up navigating through by using a more unique marker and using .next() and .prev()